# Display non-printing characters in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, ms-office

In Access 2003, when looking at data in a table, you can see black squares as placeholders for non-printing characters (carriage returns etc).

In Access 2007 these are missing.  I can't find anywhere in the settings to enable this.

Does anybody know how to make Access 2007 display non-printable characters in table data?

Comment: What does it show in Access 2007 for non printable characters?

Comment: Nothing.. they simply do not appear.  Eg: `thereisalinebreakinthemiddleofthissentence`.